# Check whether an item from a dropdown list is selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multi-select HTML dropdown list. I want to check on button click whether there is any item selected or not. If there is no element selected, then alert "Item not selected" else for selected items alert "selected".

```
if ($("#ddl1 >option").length >= 1) {

    if ($("#ddl1 >option:selected").val() == 'undefined') {
        alert("Not selected"); 
    } else {
        alert("deleted"); 
    }

} else
    alert("list empty");
```

Comment: Try the result alert($("#ddl1 >option:selected").length);,  It will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `length <= 0` here

```
if ($("#ddl1 > option").length >= 1) {
    if ($("#ddl1 > option:selected").length <= 0) {
        alert("Not selected");
    } else {
        alert("deleted");
    }
} else alert("list empty");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have a list in which three item and check value of selected dropdown

```
  if ($("#ddl1 >option").length >= 1) {

        if ($("#ddl1").val() <0) {
            alert("Not selected"); 
        } else {
            alert("deleted"); 
        }

    } else
        alert("list empty");
```